# What is the command to list only 3 subdirectories in the Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have path

```
/mnt/sws/users/paul
/mnt/sws/users/john
```

like there more than 100 users.

Under users we have subdirectories

```
/paul/Incoming/Users/Supplier
```

So, here is the issue I need find out the user which is not having Incoming directory.

Comment: It's not clear how "list only 3 subdirectories" relates to "find out the user which is not having Incoming directory".

Comment: Please do not consider 3 directories, paul and john like that we have 100+ users, under each user we supposed to have incoming directory & subdirectories, I just want to find user who is not having Incoming directory among 100+ users.

Answer (score 1):

The users who don't have Incoming directory can be listed as below:

```
find /mnt/sws/users -maxdepth 2 -type d  | grep -v Incoming
```

Comment: Does -maxdepth 2 means it seaches in the next 2 subdirectories of the user,

Comment: Yes, `maxdepth 2` in find command restricts only to two subdirectories.